# Kubuntu 22.04 stopped recognizing external monitors

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, 22.04, hp, external-monitor

My Kubuntu 22.04 installation has suddenly stopped recognizing my external monitors, which are connected to my HP Laptop through a docking station via HDMI. They were working fine up until last week.

I've already looked into possible causes and installed/reinstalled the DisplayLink drivers and made sure Secure boot is disabled. The docking station is properly recognized, and all connected USB devices work just fine. Only HDMI is not recognized at all.

I am fairly certain that an automated BIOS update happened last week, but I cannot say for certain if that was before or after the last time the monitors worked fine.

I am using Kubuntu 22.04 LTS. The screens are **not** recognized in xrandr.

Comment: I have not really been able to figure this one out. Neither my docking stations nor the ones at work function, as well as a Thunderbolt -> Ethernet dongle. I did a BIOS update to the newest version, but the problem persists. My only salvation is that a new G4 HP Thunderbolt Docking Station works fine, I haven't figured out why though.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.  After I upgraded to KUbuntu 22.04, my external monitor did not get recognized. The issue could be with my NVIDIA driver, since when I changed the driver to X.Org X Server -- Nouveau display driver, it recognized my external monitor.

Using that driver may be a workaround for this particular issue, but it does bring its own set of issues that weren't a problem with the proprietary driver, like:

- VLC not recognizing the external monitor when in deinterface mode.
- SMPlayer having the same issue.
- DaVince Resolve not installing when X.Org is the driver.

But these are battles for another day.

Again, my previous Kubuntu 20.04 worked fine.  Based on this, it's not clear if this is an Nvidia or Ubuntu issue.

Comment: Thank you NotTheDr01ds for the edits. Very much aprpeciated.

Comment: Interesting, though probably unrelated to the issue I am having. You were able to fix yours by changing the drivers. For me it seems to be hardware related, as my laptop stopped taking thunderbolt input from certain devices, which I could mitigate by changing to a more recent docking station. I haven't found out why the problem occurred, other than that it seems to be an issue with HP's firmware.